# Extjs double click event on panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I would like to add a double click event to a panel. How would I do that? So I have a panel with some html, no other events or clickable items, and I want to be able to capture a double click.

Actually any component that can display a large chunk of html would be okay as long as I can double click it.

I've searched Sencha's docs and there aren't many components with double click events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double click event is not an event of `Ext.Component`s, it's an event of `Ext.Element`. Since `Ext.Components` render `Ext.Element`s they provide a way for you to set handler on those elements the component creates without having to wait for the `render` event.

Just set a listener for the `dblclick` event, specifying which `Ext.Element` in your panel you want to handle. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-addListener

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eVzqT/

```
new Ext.Panel({
    html: 'Here I am',
    title: 'Title',
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    listeners: {
        dblclick : {
            fn: function() {
                 console.log("double click");
            },
            // You can also pass 'body' if you don't want click on the header or
            // docked elements
            element: 'el'
        }    
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

If you want to be able to handle the event from a controller, you need to relay the event from the element to the component

```
new Ext.Panel({
    html: 'Here I am',
    title: 'Title',
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    listeners: {
        dblclick : {
            fn: function(e, t) {
                 this.fireEvent('dblclick', this, e, t);
            },
            // You can also pass 'body' if you don't want click on the header or
            // docked elements
            element: 'el',
            scope: this
        }    
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

That could be abstracted into a plugin

```
/**
 * Adds an Ext.Element event to a component
 * could be improved to handle multiple events and to allow options for the event
 */
Ext.define('my.plugin.ComponentElementEvent', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugins.cmp-el-event',

    /**
     * @cfg {String} eventName Name of event to listen for, defaults to click
     */
     eventName: 'click'

    /**
     * @cfg {String} compEl Name of element within component to apply listener to
     *      defaults to 'body'
     */
     compEl: 'body',

    init: function(cmp) {
       cmp.on(this.eventName, this.handleEvent, this, {element: this.compEl});

    },
    handleEvent: function(e,t) {
        this.getCmp().fireEvent(this.eventName, this.getCmp(), e, t);
    }
});
```

And you could use the plugin like the following

```
// This panel fires a dblclick event that can be handled from controllers.
new Ext.Panel({
    html: 'Here I am',
    title: 'Title',
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    plugins: [{ptype: 'cmp-el-event', eventName: 'dblclick', compEl:'el'}
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

Comment: Sweet thanks, I totally forgot about listeners. I've been using MVC controller and added event listeners that way. Do you know if I can do something like control = { 'panel':{ listeners:{ dbclick:{ fn:function(){}, element:'el' } } }?

Comment: No you can't, Controllers can only listen for component events. You can create a plugin that adds a mouse event to a component... updating answer...

Comment: if we fire event manually is there any way to catch it via controller in control() method?

Comment: @arvindwill Yes if you are firing it from a subclass of component since the routing of events is done with component queries. If you just create something that extends Observable directly, the only way to listen to it is by having a reference to the object that fired it.